# JavaScript (ECMA) Grammar - Left Recursion Problems

Tags: javascript, c, grammar

First off: Using the LL(*) parser from the Actipro SyntaxEditor. This could apply to any LL(k) parser though.

I am currently trying to write a valid LL(k) grammar for Javascript (using the ECMA-262 reference), figuring out left recursion is okay sometimes, but I have been running against a wall in figuring out a solution for this problem. ( And may have lost focus since I have been working on this for three days non-stop now )

Okay, solution example:

Take this rule:

```
BitwiseORExpression :
    BitwiseXORExpression
    BitwiseORExpression | BitwiseXORExpression
```

which would literally become:

```
expBitwiseOR.Production = expBitwiseXOR | expBitwiseOR + @bitwiseOrSign + expBitwiseXOR;
```

and to avoid left recursion:

```
expBitwiseOR.Production = expBitwiseXOR + ( @bitwiseOrSign + expBitwiseXOR ).ZeroOrMore();
```

Simple enough. I am however stuck with more complex rules such as:

```
MemberExpression :
    PrimaryExpression
    FunctionExpression
    MemberExpression [ Expression ]
    MemberExpression . IdentifierName
    new MemberExpression Arguments
```

I have tried several things, some of which sort of work (i.e. they "work" but not as they should) and most of which don't (i.e. Left Recursive). I am honestly not hoping for a full answer or a complete solution, but maybe someone will have an idea on how to avoid this problem with a complex rule as that or something else.

No need to put this into a proper syntax for the Actipro Parser either, any mock-up code would still help!

Comment: Done and done, though it's telling me I need to wait two days before I can accept my own answer. I guess this is because I just created this account.

Comment: Thanks! I think it's normal on questions, to give other people a chance to give other/better answers that you might in the end prefer to your own solution.

Comment: what is the `23` tag for?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As it is so often with these things, shortly after desperately asking, the answer comes to you while eating a sandwich. TL;DR: Solved like this:

```
expMemberExpression.Production = 
            (
            expPrimaryExpression
            |stFunctionExpression
            | (@NewKeyword + expMemberExpression + expArguments)
            ) + expMemberExpressionHelper.ZeroOrMore();

expMemberExpressionHelper.Production = (symLiteralOpenSquare + expExpression + symLiteralCloseSquare)
            | ( @punctuator + symIdentifier );
```